# How to fix for /f loop in batch file to run multiple powershell scripts in directory

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I am trying to make the following command run multiple powershell script files located in a specified directory:

```
@echo off
for /F %%f in ('dir /b "C:\ProgramData\MyScripts\"') do Powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoLogo -WindowStyle Hidden -File C:\ProgramData\Scripts\%%f
pause
```

It works fine in the command line, however it doesn't work in a batch file (even though the "%" has been changed to "%%"). Any ideas how I can make this work?

Comment: Please be specific in what you mean by _"it doesn't work"_ as that is a pretty broad statement of a problem. If it worked from cmdline, it will work in batch, so seems something else you forgot to mention, like what happened? perhaps also explain how you launch the batch as well?

Comment: You should consider using the base for command. There is no need to capture the output of the `DIR` command when a normal `FOR` command would iterate all the files in the directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you **restructure your approach so as to avoid having to duplicate the scripts' directory path** - which may well be the source of your problem:

**Let *PowerShell* do the file enumeration**:

```
@echo off
powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -WindowStyle Hidden -Command ^
  "dir C:\ProgramData\MyScripts\*.ps1 | foreach { & $_ }"
pause
```

Note that switching from `-File` to `-Command` was necessary in order to submit an entire PowerShell command; `-NoLogo` is then not needed.

Also consider adding `-NoProfile` to suppress loading of your profile file.

As for the PowerShell command:

- `dir` is used for brevity, but note that it is an *alias*, namely for the `Get-ChildItem` command.
- `foreach` is an alias for the `ForEach-Object` cmdlet, which runs the associated script block (`{ ... }`) for each input object (file), reflected in automatic variable `$_`.
- `&` is the call operator, which is needed to invoke a command (name or path) stored in a variable.

---

If you prefer to stick with your original approach and want to fix that, see [Compo's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55384553/45375).

Answer (score 1):

The following is a method I would suggest you try:

```bat
@If Exist "C:\ProgramData\MyScripts\*.ps1" For %%A In (
    "C:\ProgramData\MyScripts\*.ps1"
)Do @Powershell -NoP -NoL -Ex Bypass -W Hidden -F "C:\ProgramData\MyScripts\%%A"
```

I have filtered to ensure that only `.ps1` files are parsed, *to exclude any non PowerShell scripts from being run*. I have also changed the location of the files to run, because it appeared that you were parsing files in one directory, `C:\ProgramData\MyScripts`, but trying to run them in another, `C:\ProgramData\Scripts`.

Note also that this will not run every file in the directory, those which are for instance hidden will not be parsed. To do that you'd be better advised to use a `For /F` loop and choose the files using the `Dir` command:

```bat
@For /F Delims^=^ EOL^= %%A In ('
    Dir /B/A-D-L "C:\ProgramData\MyScripts\*.ps1" 2^>Nul
')Do @Powershell -NoP -NoL -Ex Bypass -W Hidden -F "C:\ProgramData\MyScripts\%%A"
```

---

Please take account that each script will be run after the previous one has ended, if you wished to run each immediately after beginning the previous one, I'd suggest you open a Command Prompt window and take a look at the help information output from `Start /?`, for a method of doing so.